# React Native: User is getting a seat regardless of availability

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have put together this small application where if a user clicks on an event object with the property `numberOfSeatsAvailable` the application responds accordingly, but if no property is provided then it will default to not giving the user any seats:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

const ListScreen = () => {
  const events = [
    {
      id: "1",
      title: "Free Event for everybody with plent of seats!",
      shortDescription: "This one has number of seats available as a property",
      numberOfSeatsAvailable: 1000
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      title: "Another Free Event for everybody with plent of seats!",
      shortDescription:
        "This one does not have number of seats available as a property"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      title: "Free Event for everybody with NO CAPACITY",
      shortDescription: "This one has number of seats available as a property",
      numberOfSeatsAvailable: 1000
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      title: "Free Event for everybody with NO CAPACITY",
      shortDescription: "This one has number of seats available as a property",
      numberOfSeatsAvailable: 0
    }
  ];

  renderButton = () => {
    if (events.numberOfSeatsAvailable === 0) {
      alert("aww, I do not see any seats left");
    } else {
      alert("You got yourself a seat");
    }
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={events => events.id}
      data={events}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
          <>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.title}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.renderButton}>
              <Text style={styles.footerBtnText}>{"REGISTER FOR EVENT"}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

its not working, it keeps just giving away seats to the user even where no seats exist and where the property indicating the amount of seats does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the value of `numberOfSeatsAvailable` inside the array `events` which is not a property of array and is returning undefined. Undefined does not equal to 0. You want to check the value of the item of the array that is clicked not on the array itself. One way to solve this is to change your render logic like

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
    this.renderButton(item)
}}>
```

And change your `renderButton` function to

```
renderButton = (eventItem) => {
     if (eventItem.numberOfSeatsAvailable === 0 || eventItem.numberOfSeatsAvailable === undefined) { 
        alert("aww, I do not see any seats left");
     } else { 
        alert("You got yourself a seat"); 
     }
 };
```